# Extract string delimited by integer and newline

Tags: java

I have a method that returns a list of student records from a DB in a single string, where each line begins with a newline, then a student ID(integer), and each ends in a newline. It looks something like this:

> 1 John Doe 4.0 Nonresident Steve Jobs n/a Internet Security n/a
>
> 203 Jane Doe 2.4 Resident Bill Gates n/a Tree Lutz n/a
>
> 4343 Chris Farley 4.2 Resident B Obama n/a Trades Up PEI

I need to extract just the record requested by student ID. For instance, if the user requests ID #203, the program would print out:

> 203 Jane Doe 2.4 Resident Bill Gates n/a Tree Lutz n/a

I've looked into pattern matching and regex's but those seem to require specific characters, and I'm not sure how to parse by the int I want. I can't figure out how to loop through the string and grab just the one that begins with the requested ID. Not asking you to do my homework, but any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions? Why not split the string into an array by newline characters and return the string that starts with the number you're looking for (plus a space so you don't match 2033).

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to use regex, you can use `\d` to identify digits or numbers and `\n` for newline. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
String results; //This is your list of students

String list[] = results.split("\n");

Map students<String, String> = new HashMap<String, String>();

for(String student : list){
    String splitted[] = student.split(" ",2);
    students.put(splitted[0], student);
}
```

You can access like this:

```
System.out.println("Info of student 203: " + students.get("203"));
```

Hope it works for you, or at least, gives you an idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use `regex` for that too. Assuming there is a space (or multiple spaces) after the student id, here's what you can do:

```
int studentId = 203;

String regex = "(.|\\n)*(" + studentId + "\\s+[^\\n]+)(\\n)*(.|\\n)*";

String studentRecords = "1 John Doe 4.0 Nonresident Steve Jobs n/a Internet Security n/a\n\n203 Jane Doe 2.4 Resident Bill Gates n/a Tree Lutz n/a\n\n4343 Chris Farley 4.2 Resident B Obama n/a Trades Up PEI";

String currentStudent = studentRecords.replaceAll(regex, "$2");

System.out.println(currentStudent);
```

Console:

```
203 Jane Doe 2.4 Resident Bill Gates n/a Tree Lutz n/a
```